# How do I get Ruby Koans to work in Windows?

Tags: ruby

I just started using Ruby on windows.

There are some instructions that come with the koans but considering how they address old versions of Ruby and the fact that recent versions or Ruby already have rake and other gems there are some things that i just don't get.

For starters I'm using the Windows Command Prompt with Ruby; as the instructions with the koans suggest using command prompt I figured I would rather use this option, and no matter what I do there are errors in the files, if I do the rake gen, in return I get a message which states that no rakefile is there to be found, I trace it and I see the folders in which ruby is installed.

If I open the koans with Notepad++ i just get gibberish.

And it seems all the help out there is intended for people who already know code and many make different statements about the same characters.

Comment: What do you mean "gibberish"? Is the stuff all on one line?

Comment: although its not really related to your question - save yourself some time and dont try doing ruby on windows, if you dont like osx, run a vm with linux or something

Comment: I have downloaded and unpacked Koans. I `cd`ed to that directory (where there is many about_*.rb files). I've run `rake` (`ruby path_to_enlightenment.rb` is the same) and it showed me colorful results (I think it might be black and white and some weird symbols if you haven't installed proper things). I followed http://rubykoans.com/windows#the_path and I fixed first file. Try (if you haven't already done) do the same and if still doesn't work, show us errors.

Comment: @mymlyn Why? For a basic (or beginner) user, RailsInstaller (Ruby 1.9.3 and... I haven't know 2.0 & 2.1) and RubyInstaller (RubyInstaller 1.9.3-p551, 2.0.0-p598 and 2.1.5). It's just few clicks and you have all stuffs.

Comment: I am flagging this question as OT > unclear. Without error log messages, we do not know your exact issue. What is "gibberish" in npp? Why are you installing Ruby (that you expect to be old) from RK, and not RubyInstaller? (Which Ruby's official site points Windows users to.)